# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n p_n}$ where $p_n$ is the n-th prime number converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n p_n}$$ where $p_n$ is the n-th prime number converge? I try to check in WolframAlpha and it does not converge, but I don't quite understand the proof due to it's lack of detail. Can someone please provide me with with explanation as to why?

If it does, what number does it converge to?

Comment: Hint: $p_n > n$ – What exactly did you check in WolframAlpha, and what makes you think that the series does not converge?

Comment: since $p_n\geq n$ for all $n\geq 2$, the series does converges.

Comment: $p_n\sim n \ln n$

Comment: If you're talking about [this WA query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+1%2F%28n*+prime%28n%29%29%2C+n+from+1+to+inf), I have no idea how it reaches the conclusion that it diverges. It says it uses the integral test (which would not be my first choice due to the discrete nature of the function $n\mapsto p_n$), and then it stops, because I don't have pro access.

Comment: The value is a bit larger than $0.84897$.

Comment: @Arthur. Replace *inf* by $10^4$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That gives us a good approximation, assuming the series _does_ converge, but it will not in any way help us conclude that the series actually converges, and it does not help us understand why WA says it diverges.

Comment: @Arthur. I agree but it is so obvious that it must converge

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Using other means, sure. Using WA and your $10^4$ query? Not even remotely.

Comment: As all of you have pointed out, the results should be somewhere in between $P(2)$ and $\zeta(2)$, where $P(z)$ is the prime zeta function. A rough estimate based on logarithmic mean would be something like 0.8

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A124012 for a numerical estimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since not every number is prime, $p_n\ge n$. Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{np_n}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$
Therefore the series does converge, although I am not sure what the series converges to.